# Tridion Publishing queue stuck at Committing deployment but items are getting insterted into the broker DB

Tags: publishing

Items in the Tridion Publishing queue are stuck at 'Committing Deployment' but items are getting inserted into the broker DB

I have a newly upgraded from SDL Tridion 2011 to 2013 and after publishing pages or images I see items getting stuck in the 'Committing Deployment' phase.

The page contents are successfully inserted into the broker db but the publishing status is not shown as success. It gets stuck at committing deployment for a long time instead.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about your setup? Http deployer? .Net? Java? Service? Have you checked the deployer and core logs? Configure your logback.xml to set the level to DEBUG. You'll probably see what happens then.

Comment: logs didn't give any info regarding this . i'm using .net 3.5 java version "1.6.0_25" .

Comment: Confirm also if you are publishing to a share location.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for your valuable responses and i figured this issue myself by activating the tcmpublisherlog which gave me a clue giving an error saying about  a connection failure regarding MSDTC process and firewalls .
The issue is i have CME configured in one server and the db server in another so we need to have the host entries in both the servers for each other and the DTC ports has to be enabled in the firewall settings .

Use [DTCPing.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2868) tool for checking the connectivity of each server from the other .

By enabling the port i was able to see the status as success .

Answer (score 4):

I have seen this problem before when you are publishing to a share location. If that is the case I would suggest to temporary configure for write in the local file system and see what's wrong with the shared location. Is possible that has nothing to do with the product setup, but with the infrastructure

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the similar issue which was encountered on **SDL Tridion 2011**.

***Hotfix:*** [CD_2011.0.1.75913](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2011/index.aspx) *(Login Required)*

Contact the customer support to check whether there is a similar hotfix on **Tridion 2013**